# RelayCommand with parameters

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I am using the MVVM Light toolkit in my application and trying to learn about passing a command.
I have the following XAML code snippet:

```
<s:ScatterView x:Name="swPicture" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Scatter_Thumbnail}"/>
    <Button Content="Info" Width="40" Height="40"
                         Command="{Binding GetInfoCommand}"
                           Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Element swPicture contains items source coming from Pictures collection. As a test only for the time being I just have 1 single picture.

How can I pass as a parameter to the command, the single first picture from the Pictures which is in my swPicture Element ?

For the time being I am able to trigger the single command without parameter with following command handler in the model as defined bellow:

```
GetInfoCommand = new RelayCommand<Picture>(
            action=>
                {
                    GetMetaData();
                },
                g=>true); //Execute method
```

The idea is that I need to pass the first Picture from the collection as a parameter to my command in order to pass it to GetMetaData which will have accept this parameter

How can I update my XAML code and the command in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you don't need a parameter at all, since your view model has both the Pictures collection and the GetInfoCommand - GetMetaData method has access to the collection and you can just access the first element from there.

If your question is how to pass parameters - you can just set the value of the CommandParameter property of your button to some value or bind it to whatever you want and when you press the button - the Execute and CanExecute methods will be passed that value as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

CommandParameter do this

```
<s:ScatterView x:Name="swPicture" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Scatter_Thumbnail}"/>
    <Button Content="Info" Width="40" Height="40"
                         Command="{Binding GetInfoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Pictures[0]}"
                           Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```